# How do I create a single array of object from nested array of obejcts mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I am new to Mongodb and don't know much about aggregates how do I change below object to desired single array of object.

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "First Title",
    des: "This is desc",
    contents: [
      {
        id: "1",
        title: "content-1 title",
        des: "This is desc"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        title: "Content-2 title",
        des: "This is desc"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Second Title is Here",
    des: "This is desc",
    contents: [
      {
        id: "1",
        title: "content-1 title",
        des: "This is desc"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        title: "Content-2 title",
        des: "This is desc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My Desired Out Single array :

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "First Title",
    des: "This is desc"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "content-1 title",
    des: "This is desc"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Content-2 title",
    des: "This is desc"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Second Title is Here",
    des: "This is desc"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "content-1 title",
    des: "This is desc"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Content-2 title",
    des: "This is desc"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      contents: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              id: "$id",
              title: "$title",
              des: "$des"
            }
          ],
          "$contents"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$contents"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$contents"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cIJXIpAz6R_)

Comment: Wow Great Answer. But still have some issue, all contents should be shown below main object. order is changed in result. also need to sort according to top one id

Comment: I update my answer to solve the problem of order changing. If you want to have only one object instead of six, you can group them all. Add $sort stage after $unwind` stage can sort documents.

Comment: mongoplayground link now did't work

Comment: @RammeharSharma ok I fix it